# Class TimeSheetEntryField missing from WorkforceTimesheet in S4 SDK

Tags: s4sdk

I am updating one of our S4 SDK projects to use the latest version of the SDK and I noticed then when I try to build the project I got the error:

```
cannot find symbol>  [ERROR] symbol:   class TimeSheetEntryField
```

When I look at the Javadocs I can see that this class existed in version **2.7.0** but is missing in the next version **2.8.0**

This import throws an error as it cannot find the class in the newer version:

```
com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.workforcetimesheet.TimeSheetEntryField;
```

I can't see any notice of deprecation. Can you help?

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class has been moved to a new package `com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.workforcetimesheet.field` (see [Javadoc](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/b579bf8578954412aea2b458e8452201/1.0/en-US/index.html?com/sap/cloud/sdk/s4hana/datamodel/odata/namespaces/workforcetimesheet/field/TimeSheetEntryField.html)) with version 2.8.0. Please update your import accordingly by adding `.field` to the package name.

As mentioned in the [release notes](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/6c02295dfa8f47cf9c08a19f2e172901/1.0/en-US/index.html#version-2.8.0), this was necessary to avoid potential name clashes in the virtual data model of the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK.

Comment: Thank you Henning, sorry I should have seen that myself. Thanks for your help.